# Dynamically loading ADO.NET providers in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, ado.net

I'm currently looking to update some of our software from the classic .NET Framework to .NET Standard / Core (i.e. .NET 6), which includes ADO.NET providers.

We have a test tool written in .NET to test these ADO.NET providers, and it was originally written for the .NET framework as well, and used `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory` to allow it to be agnostic to the actual provider being tested.

Originally these providers needed to be set up in `machine.config` / `app.config`, but I've found that this no longer works in .NET Core, and you need to register the factories yourself with `DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory` at runtime.

I've tried to modify the program to do this with the overload that takes a 'assembly-qualified name' (i.e. what was used in the config files), but I get errors about the assembly being unable to be loaded, though I've placed it (and its dependencies) in the same directory as the program (this worked when building with the .NET framework). This is all currently on Windows.

So I guess my question is: how does DbProviderFactories.GetFactory resolve assemblies in .NET Core?

Do I need to do something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support to load the ADO.Net provider myself, and use the DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory overload that takes an assembly?